# Pandas - transpose one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having difficulty using transpose with pandas.

I have the following df:

```
date         name    quantity
1/1/2018     A       5
1/1/2018     B       6
1/1/2018     C       7
1/2/2018     A       9
1/2/2018     B       8
1/2/2018     C       6
```

I eventually want to create a pairwise correlation for all the names and their quantities on each date. To to that end, I'm trying to create the following output from this df first:

```
 date       A    B    C
 1/1/2018   5    6    7
 1/2/2018   9    8    6
```

The transpose is difficult to me since I can get duplicate column headers, but I also don't want to lose any data by dropping them first. I have a feeling the answer may be with a panda utility that I don't really use and I may be tunneling on transpose...

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off using `groupby` with a multiindex, or `pivot`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Since you aren't performing an aggregation, [`pd.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) should be preferred to `groupby` / `pivot_table`:

```
res = df.pivot(index='date', columns='name', values='quantity')

print(res)

name      A  B  C
date             
1/1/2018  5  6  7
1/2/2018  9  8  6
```

If you wish you can use `reset_index` to elevate `date` to a column.

Comment: dude you rock! Thank you for the reset_index tip. It would be super helpful to show a example for those in the future that come by this example.

Answer (score 3):

By no means is my proposed solution better than jpp's. I just happened to run into the same problem and solved it differently.

```
df.set_index(['date', 'name']).unstack()
```

The result looks a little messier too but it worked in my case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `groupby` solution, although it's highly impractical when compared to the `pivot` method. I would only recommend this as an exercise to become familiar with pandas' indices.

```py
# Get values of 'quantity' for each date
x = df.groupby('date')['quantity'].agg(list)
# Insert these values into a new data frame
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=x.index, data=x.to_list(), columns=df['name'].unique())
```

This returns:

```
            A   B   C
date            
1/1/2018    5   6   7
1/2/2018    8   9   6
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you end up here and have a dataframe with more then 3 columns:

```
date         category    name    quantity
1/1/2018     Alpha       A       5
1/1/2018     Beta        B       6
1/1/2018     Alpha       C       7
1/2/2018     Alpha       A       9
1/2/2018     Beta        B       8
1/2/2018     Beta        C       6
```

you can include that in the index and still use `reset_index` to "unpivot" it:

```
res = df.pivot(index=['date', 'category'], columns='name', values='quantity').reset_index()
```

with the output:

```
date      category A     B     C             
1/1/2018  Alpha    5     None  7        
1/1/2018  Beta     None  6     None
1/2/2018  Alpha    9     None  None
1/2/2018  Beta     None   8    6
```